# Distributed outbound http rate limiter

Tags: go, distributed, rate-limiting

I have a microservice architecture application with multiple services polling an external API. The external API has a rate limiter of 600 requests per minute. How can I have all of my instances together stay below the shared 600 rate limit?

Google only brought me 3 solutions, the most promising being:

- [myntra/golimit](https://github.com/myntra/golimit) the most promising of the three, but I literally do not have a clue how to set that up.
- [wallstreetcn/rate](https://github.com/wallstreetcn/rate) which only seems to reject when limit has been reached (my app needs to wait till it can make the request) and the `Every` function in the `rate.NewLimiter` func seems to be a different import / dependency which i cannot figure out  which it is
- [manavo/go-rate-limiter](https://github.com/manavo/go-rate-limiter) has a "soft" limit which, obviously, could get me over the limit. Some endpoints I dont really mind if I cant access them for a few seconds, but other endpoint requests should work as much as possible.

Currently I have an amateur solution. The code below allows to me set a limit per minute and it sleeps in between requests to spread the requests over the minute. This client rate limit is per instance, thus I would have to hardcode divide the 600 requests by the amount of instances.

```
var semaphore = make(chan struct{}, 5)
var rate = make(chan struct{}, 10)

func init(){
    // leaky bucket
    go func() {
        ticker := time.NewTicker(100 * time.Millisecond)
        defer ticker.Stop()
        for range ticker.C {
            _, ok := <-rate
            // if this isn't going to run indefinitely, signal
            // this to return by closing the rate channel.
            if !ok {
                return
            }
        }
}()
```

And inside the function that makes the http API requests.

```
rate <- struct{}{}

    // check the concurrency semaphore
    semaphore <- struct{}{}
    defer func() {
        <-semaphore
}()
```

How can I have all of my instances together stay below the shared 600 rate limit?

Preferences: 
 - Rate limit counter based on a key, so multiple counters can be set.
 - Spread the requests over the set duration, so that 600 requests are not sent in the first 30 seconds but rather the full minute duration.

Comment: What happens if you go over 600? Presumably you get a 429 response or similar? What if you just handle 429s in a reasonable way?

Comment: We are using a leaky bucket rate limiter available here: https://github.com/jwells131313/danaides.  I'm not really sure it meets your use case, but in our team we found it extremely good for streaming use cases (we were limiting the rate over a websocket).  Not sure it would be as good in your use case.  Disclaimer:  I wrote the library but it is being used by production software in the Oracle cloud

Comment: @Flimzy I can catch the error probably but some services are more critical and tied to a user request, cant have the user wait till the limit finally resets.

Comment: @jwells131313 sounds good. Can you give me more details? The code on your github seems to be client only, dont see how it shares the rate limit with other running instances.

Comment: But you're already requiring your user to wait until the timer resets. The only logical difference between rate limiting yourself, and retrying on 429, is the number of network requests. Granted, that can be non-trivial, but if you expect to usually be under the limit, handling 429s could be much easier.

Comment: @Flimzy i expect to hit the cap every minute. handling the errors would take more resources than limiting them

Comment: Not sure what kind of answers you get, but is it really necessary to make them from several machines? Sounds to me like you would rather like a single (HA) instance to poll and fan out the processing, which can be easily done via one of the various message queues.

Comment: This seems to me like a job for a proxy or API gateway in front of your service instances, responsible for throttling. Nginx for example can do this.

Comment: @YSTai and Adrian lead me to the probable solution (still working it out) found a forward proxy called Cuttle which is a golang proxy designed for centralized rate limiting. Ill be working out this solution, when i got it working i will update with an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want a global rate limiter, you need a place to maintain distributed state, such as zookeeper. Usually, we don't want to pay the overhead. Alternatively, you can set up a forward proxy (https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httputil/#ReverseProxy), do rate limit in it.

Comment: Using a forward proxy with a rate limiter is exactly what i was looking for. in my solution I am now using Cuttle which is based on Goproxy.

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak to the libraries you found, but a [leaky bucket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaky_bucket) rate limiter is quite simple. You need some kind of shared transactional storage. Each bucket (or rate limiter) is then simply an integer and a time value. The integer is the number of drops in the bucket at the particular time. Every time you have to apply the rate limit, subtract the number of drops that leaked since the last update, then add one, then check if the number of drops is within the capacity of the bucket.

We are using Redis for this sort of thing. To make this transactional in Redis a script is required (see [SCRIPT LOAD](https://redis.io/commands/script-load) and [EVALSHA](https://redis.io/commands/evalsha)). In an SQL database a `SELECT FOR UPDATE` followed by an `UPDATE` statement would achieve the same thing, for instance. This is our Redis script:

```lua
-- replicate_commands allows us to use the TIME command. We depend on accurate
-- (and reasonably consistent) timestamps. Multiple clients may have
-- inacceptable clock drift.
redis.replicate_commands()

local rate = tonumber(ARGV[1]) -- how many drops leak away in one second
local cap = tonumber(ARGV[2]) -- how many drops fit in the bucket
local now, _ = unpack(redis.call('TIME'))

-- A bucket is represented by a hash with two keys, n and t. n is the number of
-- drops in the bucket at time t (seconds since epoch).
local xs = redis.call('HMGET', KEYS[1], 'n', 't')
local n = tonumber(xs[1])
local t = tonumber(xs[2])

if type(n) ~= "number" or type(t) ~= "number" then
    -- The bucket doesn't exist yet (n and t are false), or someone messed with
    -- our hash values. Either way, pretend the bucket is empty.
    n, t = 0, now
end

-- remove drops that leaked since t
n = n - (now-t)*rate
if n < 0 then
    n = 0
end

-- add one drop if it fits
if n < cap then
    n = n + 1
else
    n = cap
end

redis.call('HMSET', KEYS[1], 'n', n, 't', now)
redis.call('EXPIRE', KEYS[1], math.floor(n/rate) + 1)

return n
```

Example call for 10 drops per second with a capacity of 10 drops:

```
EVALSHA <SHA_IN_HEX> 1 rate-limit:my-bucket 10 10
```

The script returns the number of drops in the bucket. If that number is equal to the capacity, you can either sleep for a short duration and try again, or reject the request outright, depending on your requirements.

Note the the script never returns a value larger than the capacity, resulting in a recovery time of no more than a tenth of a second in your case. That may not be what you need since you are trying to match a third-party rate limiter. I.e. you may be okay with overflowing the bucket, resulting in a longer recovery time after a burst of requests.